# WPF MVVM dynamic binding of UserControls and show records as per selected design

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I need a help in my project.Could not get any proper solution as I want. I explain you my scenario here.

I am working on WPF project with MVVM pattern, where I have Main Windows screen, on load of Main Windows screen it should be load blank, and only one label is there. On Click of that Label I have to open new form that is Widget Screen and Widget Screen have multiple buttons(in number of 12) with Images.

Now, on click of any button, I want that particular button name or parameter, so accordingly that name or parameter I have to find User Controls from views and render User Controls on Main Windows screen with collection of 20 records. If again I click on Main Windows label and select another button from widget screen then it should load another selected User Controls will be bind ob Main Windows screen.

So, in short as per selected design from widget screen all records should be show in Main Windows using User Controls.
This below is my widget screen and from that I can select design for my collection that shows in Main windows screen.
[image]

this is my Main Windows screen code, currently it is binding static User Control that I mentioned directly into controls from that 12 user controls one of them is UserControlColumn1XL, How it should be dynamically changed with whole scenario?

```
<Window x:Class="TechMedic.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:uc ="clr-namespace:TechMedic.View.UserControls"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TechMedic"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TechMedic.View.UserControls"
    xmlns:data="clr-namespace:TechMedic.Data"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="Black"
    Title="Main Window}" WindowState="Maximized" MinWidth="750" >

<StackPanel>    
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="Black" BorderBrush="White">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource TransparentStyle}" Command="{Binding OnClickNormalCommand}" CommandParameter="Normal" Foreground="LightSkyBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12pt" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NormalCollection.Count, StringFormat='Normal: {0}'}" Padding="0,5, 0, 5" Foreground="{Binding IsNormalColor}" />
            </Button>
            </Border>
            <Border Name="UserControl1BorderNormal" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0" >
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NormalCollection}" Name="ListNormal" Margin="4,0" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <controls:UserControlColumn1XL HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: So WidgetScreen is some other window, and you want to display item selected from WingetScreen on MainWindow?

Comment: Yes, and on MainWindow it is having list of 20 records of collection when item is selected from widget screen. So selected item should show be shown 20 time in MainWindows dynamically.

Comment: so, you'r asking about solution how to communicate these two window, aren't you?

Comment: Yes as well as dynamically bind and change user controls in MainWindows screen as per selection from Widget screen.

Comment: You could use some kind of Messenger/EventAggregator to communicate.

Comment: But what for dynamic binding of user controls to widget screen and change according selection?

Comment: Check this: [Wpf MVVM dynamic binding of usercontrols and show records as per selected design](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1255014/Wpf-MVVM-dynamic-binding-of-usercontrols-and-show)